# Chmod from IntelliJ on Windows?

Tags: intellij-idea, file-permissions, chmod

I'm using PyCharm on Windows. How can I set executable bit or modify other permissions like Linux `chmod`? I found [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000682250-Changing-File-permissions) only and nothing suitable in plugins but still hope there's a better solution then switching to Linux console for that purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, but I wasn't very eager to install yet another plugin. If you happen to use Git, you can do it from PyCharm's terminal using the following command:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x path-to-your-file
```